# Translation Management Library - Workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, library

Can someone help me with this?

I need to edit the translation management workflow and add a few things,
but I can't find it anywhere...

So is it possible to edit this workflow? And where can i find it?
(it isn't listed in Sharepoint Designer when i click on the "workflows" tab)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it isn't possible since you guys also don't know the anwser. If someone should know the anwser, I'll reopen this

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint designer goto the library for which you have created the workflow. There you can see an area for Workflows. You will surely find it there.

Comment: Like I said, it isn't listed in Sharepoint designer in the area for workflows... any other ideas?

Comment: can you open your site in explorer view and check it there.